# Refering to Database Error

Tags: function, dataset, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to visual basic so forgive me in advance.
I'm trying to reference a data table from a module and I get “reference not a shared member requires object” error. I can’t figure out why.

```
Public Module myFuncs

Public Function get_name()

    Dim lotto As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim first As String
    Dim last As String
    Dim fullname As String

    counter = Database11DataSet.Tbl_names.Rows.Count
    lotto = Int((counter - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1)

    Dim nameq = From n In Database11DataSet.Tbl_names.AsEnumerable()
                Where n.ID = lotto
                Select n

    For Each n In nameq
        first = n.first
    Next
    lotto = Int((counter - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1)
```

… 'does the same for the last name

```
Return fullname
End function
```

Comment: Which line is the error happening on? Is it a compile-time error, rather than a runtime one?

Comment: Which line? The compiler should be highlighting that to you as well, or it will be shown in the "errors" window.

Comment: 3 errors on 3 lines that have the "Database11DataSet.Tbl_names" refernce.

Comment: I guess i need to declare it somehow. I just cant figure out how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, your problems were on the lines that used:

```
Database11DataSet.Tbl_names
```

Within your code, `Database11DataSet` appears to be a type rather than an object; the only methods that can be called on a type are shared (or, depending upon the language, static). From [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Static_methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29#Static_methods):

> Static methods neither require an instance of the class nor can they implicitly access the data (or this, self, Me, etc.) of such an instance. A static method is distinguished in some programming languages with the static keyword placed somewhere in the method's signature.

In your case, you should be able to resolve this by creating an instance of `Database11DataSet` at the top of your code, and then using that in place of the type:

```
Public Function get_name()

    ...

    Dim data as new Database11DataSet()

    counter = data.Tbl_names.Rows.Count
    lotto = Int((counter - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1)

    Dim nameq = From n In data.Tbl_names.AsEnumerable()
                Where n.ID = lotto
                Select n

    ...

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks,
I did that and no errors . BUT..
it seems that it treats all the tables as empty. Count = 0

Comment: That's worthwhile asking as a different question, purely to attract others into offering their own solutions. Personally, I'd stick a SQL trace on and check that it's actually making the database calls, and to the database server you're expecting it to.

Comment: @Jonathan Just as a reminder, if this answer (and answers to any other questions that you have asked) solves your problem, you can mark it as 'accepted' and potentially help other people with the same issue in the future.

Comment: Thanks.
sorry for that, it's my first time in the forum :)